# What double back slash followed by two dots means within a path in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to find a location of a specific file that is used in a project edited in Visual Studio 2017. And the path is a Path Variable predefined by the project.

The path is something like:

"Project\something\abc"\\"..\..\something2\afile"

Why is there a double back slash in the middle of the full path? What does it mean?

Note: 
The double quote in the middle of the path is added so that the double slash can be shown.

This path variable can be found in "Additional Include Directory" in the project Property. The project is an open source C++ project. The Property window is already maximized so that the entire path is shown on the screen.

Here is a snap shot:

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing that?  Typically, that just means the path is too long to show it to you on the screen.

Comment: Context is really important here.  Where are you seeing this?

Comment: Since it is an open source project, please post a link to the exact place where you see that or give more context.

Comment: I got no further information. But if you guys haven't seen a double back slash in the middle of a path in your entire career life, then, probably it is a Visual Studio mistake.

Comment: Image might really help here.

Comment: A snap shot is included, please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I don't know enough about your project to know what screen we are looking at in Visual Studio, but you can always work backwards.  Do a search on your harddrive for "swig.exe" or "protoc.exe", etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input, have I provided enough information? Is this question detailed enough to be reopened?

Comment: That image doesn't provide any context.  We wanted to know where you see these. We didn't need proof that you were seeing them.

Comment: Amy, all context is provided. check my last updated edit for where the path is.

Comment: It's probably because a relative path (e.g. `\..\..\foo`) is being appended to an absolute path (e.g. `C:\Foo\Bar\ `). Multiple backslashes in a row are typically meaningless as the OS will just treat it as a single backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double backslash has no extra meaning or effect. It might come if your project is building a path or filename by using a setting like `$(directory_variable)\..\..\..\3rdpartypublic`. If `directory_variable` contains the trailing backslash, then you would end up with a double backslash. That does not cause any harm. But if you want to get rid of it, then you just need to change the setting to `$(directory_variable)..\..\..\3rdpartypublic`